# Meteor login with facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-useraccounts

I have a meteor app, with packages :

```
useraccounts:bootstrap; 
service-configuration; 
accounts-facebook;
```

The facebook side was configured to allow requests from localhost. When using the register/signin with facebook from the atForm, a popup appears

**EDIT**

The popup is actually not empty but displays a message 'login complete, click to close' but closed fast because that's how I configured it on the facebook side.

And the console logs an error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' undefined
```

**EDIT**

Here is the service conf:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
    service: 'facebook'
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
    service: 'facebook',
    appId: 'removed',
    secret: 'removed'
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is the client side code :

```
Template.atForm.events({
    'click #at-facebook': function(event) {
        console.log("facebook click");
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
          requestPermissions: ['email', 'user_friends']
          }, function (err) {
          if (err)
            Session.set('errorMessage', err.reason || 'Unknown error');
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
When registering with facebook the user created is as follow :

```
{ createdAt: Thu Jan 21 2016 16:00:08 GMT+0100 (CET),
I20160121-16:00:08.108(1)?   _id: 'Kgs3WswMdB9hsxMfp',
I20160121-16:00:08.108(1)?   services: 
I20160121-16:00:08.108(1)?    { facebook: 
I20160121-16:00:08.108(1)?       { accessToken: 'removed',
I20160121-16:00:08.108(1)?         expiresAt: 1458562023670,
I20160121-16:00:08.109(1)?         id: 'removed',
I20160121-16:00:08.109(1)?         email: 'removed',
I20160121-16:00:08.109(1)?         name: 'Mathieu Kudla',
I20160121-16:00:08.109(1)?         first_name: 'Mathieu',
I20160121-16:00:08.110(1)?         last_name: 'Kudla',
I20160121-16:00:08.110(1)?         link: 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/removed/',
I20160121-16:00:08.110(1)?         gender: 'male',
I20160121-16:00:08.110(1)?         locale: 'fr_FR',
I20160121-16:00:08.110(1)?         age_range: [Object] } } }
```

This seems to indicate that the facebook handshake was successful?

What is causing that error? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Both the facebook login client side code and your server side service configuration code.

Comment: Just edited to include that. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks those details help; do you have any logs on the server side, or do you only get the message "Exception while invoking method 'login' undefined" on the client side?

Comment: Also, do you use any kind of schema for mongo that would require certain fields to be set on the user profile? Also try adding this code on the server side: Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) { console.log(user); return user; });

Comment: That's all I got, which is part of the problem, I don't event know what is throwing the error...

Comment: I just did that and edited in the results. This seem to indicate that the error is not thrown by fb? No schema on the users collection btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I kinda solved it.

I digged in the log-in attempts and noticed that the oauth service was not properly paired with the user. I don't know why that is or if there is a better solve but I added the line :

```
if (user.services) { var service = _.pairs(user.services)[0]; }
```

to my onCreateUser hook and appended the user object properly before returning it. It seems to have done the trick but I don't know what I was not doing properly the first time...